# Promote python package in azure devops within the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, pypi

In Azure Devops you can have retention policies on the level of all packages, which means that we only retain a limit number of versions. You can "promote" packages, but this is a manual step. We would prefer to have that step within our pipeline (with a separate step that requires approval to promote a package).

How can you do that?

I'm not managing to make it work by following the steps in the similar question for [NuGet packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594269/automatically-promote-a-nuget-packge-using-a-relese-definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to use script to Promote python packages.

I suggest that you can use the following Rest APIs:

```
Post https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/pypi/packagesBatch?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "viewId":"prerelease/release"
    },
    "operation":0,
    "packages":[{
        "id":"{packagename}",
        "version":"{versionnumber}"
        }]
}
```

Or you can use the Rest API:

```
PATCH https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/pypi/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "views": {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/views/-",
    "value": "Release"
  }
}
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Promote packages and manage feed views in Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/views?view=azure-devops&tabs=python)]

You can use the Rest API: [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get all version of the python package.

```
Get https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organizationanme}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedId}/packages?packageNameQuery={packagename}&includeAllVersions=true&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

We can use PowerShell script to run the Rest APIs above to promote the python packages.

For example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$packagename= "packagename"

$GetPackageversion="https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedId}/packages?packageNameQuery=$($packagename)&includeAllVersions=true&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetPackageversion -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json 

foreach($versionobj in $response.value.versions)
{
    $version = $versionobj.version
    echo $version
    $PromoteView="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{FeedId}/pypi/packagesBatch?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

    $body= "{
        `"data`":
        {
            `"viewId`":`"release`"
        },
        `"operation`":0,
        `"packages`":[{
            `"id`":`"$packagename`",
            `"version`":`"$version`"
            }]
    }


    "

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PromoteView -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json 


}
```

PowerShell Sample with the PATCH method:

```
$token = "PAT"

$packagename= "packagename"

$GetPackageversion="https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{FeedId}/packages?packageNameQuery=$($packagename)&includeAllVersions=true&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetPackageversion -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json 

foreach($versionobj in $response.value.versions)
{
    $version = $versionobj.version
    echo $version
    $PromoteView="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{FeedId}/pypi/packages/$($packagename)/versions/$($version)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

    $body= "
     {
       `"views`": {
        `"op`": `"add`",
        `"path`": `"/views/-`",
        `"value`": `"PreRelease`"
         }
      }

    "

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PromoteView -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $body -ContentType application/json 


}
```

Result: The two powershell samples can achieve the same result

[image]

In Pipeline, you can add an agentless job before the job to run the PowerShell script. Then you can add the task: [Manual validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) in the agentless job.

For example:

[image]

In this case, before running the Powershell script to promote the python package. It will require approve from target users.

Comment: My use case was a bit more simple: I don't need to iterate all versions, but I know the package-name and version :) I used the REST API you provided - I think for the answer it could help if we add the final yaml. Do you mind if I add it?